Корзина в виде таблицы Woocommerce
Хочу реализовать корзину в магазине woocommerce в виде таблицы, как это можно сделать? Должно быть несколько строк. На каждую свой товар, с соответствующей информацией (наименование, количество, цена, стоимость).
Нужно получить что-то такое:

Корзина по умолчанию в виде таблицы. (По другому я даже не представляю как может быть)

@SeVlad, я картинку добавил как должно выглядеть

И что должна сказать непонятная картинка (первый и последние три столбца вообще полный левак - там должны быть числа)? Ты вообще видел корзину в WC? Зайди и посмотри.

Корзина выглядит приблизительно так https://i.imgur.com/UJk1BHP.jpeg (нюансы оформления зависят от темы)

Спасибо, очень помог. Надеюсь у тебя в жизни всё хорошо.
